# awk to update file based on match in 3 fields in two files

Tags: awk

Trying to use `awk` to store the value of `$5` in `file1` in array `x`. That array `x` is then used to search `$4` of `file1` to find aa match (I use x[2] to skip the header in file1). Since `$4` can have multiple strings in it seperated by a `,` (comma), I split them and iterate througn each split looking for a match. Each split is then stored in array and compared to `x[2]` for a match. In the example below all the `$4`values matc, but that will not always be the case. The pattern `c.` is extracted and stored as `VAL` from each matching `$4`. The `awk` below will hopefully do that but where I am struggling is in order for `$6` in `file1` to be updated, the `$2` and `$3` and array value must match `$4` and `$5`and `$6` in `file2`. If that is true then `$6` in `file1` is updated with the values of `$1` and `$2` from `file2`. Line 4 is an example of this because the `NM_000138.4` matches array `x[2]` and the `c.` value up to the `:` (colon) matches `$6` in `file2`. So all the conditions are meet to update `$6` in `file1`. Line2 satisfies all but the `c.` value in `VAL` does not match `$6` in `file2`, so `file1` is not updated. I hope this is a good start and that I didn't over-complicate things (though I may have and there is probably a better way). I haven't tested the `awk` but included it as a stating point with comments as to my thinking. Thank you :).

**file1**  `tab-delimited`

```
R_Index Chr Start   AAChange.refGeneWithVer MajorTranscript HGMD C1 C2
1   chr15   48720526    FBN1:NM_000138.4:exon57:c.6997+17C>G:p.?    NM_000138.4 . . .
2   chr15   48741091    FBN1:NM_000138.4:exon46:c.5546-1G>A:p.? NM_000138.4 . . .
3   chr15   48807637    FBN1:NM_000138.4:exon12:c.1415G>A:p.Cys472Tyr   NM_000138.4 . . .
4   chr15   48741091    FBN1:NM_000138.4:exon46:c.5546-1G>A:p.?,FBN1:NM_000138.4:exon46:c.5546-1G>T:p.? NM_000138.4 . . .
```

**file2**  `tab-delimited`

```
HGMD ID Class   Gene Symbol chromosome  start   hgvs
CS057007    DM  FBN1    chr15   48797346    c.1838-2A>G
CS057008    DM  FBN1    chr15   48741091    c.5546-1G>T
```

**desired output** `tab-delimited`

```
R_Index Chr Start   AAChange.refGeneWithVer MajorTranscript HGMD C1 C2
1   chr15   48720526    FBN1:NM_000138.4:exon57:c.6997+17C>G:p.?    NM_000138.4 . . .
2   chr15   48741091    FBN1:NM_000138.4:exon46:c.5546-1G>A:p.? NM_000138.4 . . .
3   chr15   48807637    FBN1:NM_000138.4:exon12:c.1415G>A:p.Cys472Tyr   NM_000138.4 . . .
4   chr15   48741091    FBN1:NM_000138.4:exon46:c.5546-1G>A:p.?,FBN1:NM_000138.4:exon46:c.5546-1G>T:p.? NM_000138.4 CS057008 DM . .
```

**awk**

```
awk '
BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }
  FNR==NR {x[NR]=$5}  # store value in $5 in array x 
  $4 ~ x[2] {      # if $4 matches x[2]
  match($4,"NM"].*],);  # regex match from NM to till , in 4rd field
   val=substr($4,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-2); # store substring value that starts from RSTART+1 to RLENGTH-2 using $4 in val
   NM=split($4, array,",");   # Split $4 on "," and storing it's length(array's length) to variable named num. 
      for(i=1;i<=NM;i++){ # Starting a loop which will start from value 1 of variable i to till value of variable num
       if(array[i] ~  x[2]){  # Check condition if any array's value is equal to array x[2] skipping header
       if (match(NM[i],/c[.].:/)) {  # extract pattern c. in each split from c. to :
       VAL=substr(NM[n],RSTART+2) # store each c. from split in VAL
          }
         }
        }
       }
   {a[$4,$5,$6]=$1,$2; next} a[$2,$3]{$6=a[$2,$3]}1' file1 file2  # update $6 in file1 if condition is met
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following and let me know if this helps you.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$NF]=$1 OFS $2;next} {split($4,array,":");for(i in array){if(array[i] in a){print $0,a[array[i]];next}}} 1' Input_file2 Input_file1
```

Adding a non-one liner form of same too now.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  a[$NF]=$1 OFS $2;
  next}
{
  split($4,array,":");
  for(i in array){
    if(array[i] in a){
      print $0,a[array[i]];
      next}}
}
1
'  Input_file2  Input_file1


awk 'FNR==NR{a[$NF]=$1 OFS $2;next} {split($4,array,":");for(i in array){if(array[i] in a){print $0,a[array[i]];next}}} 1'  Input_file2  Input_file1
R_Index Chr Start   AAChange.refGeneWithVer MajorTranscript HGMD C1 C2
1   chr15   48720526    FBN1:NM_000138.4:exon57:c.6997+17C>G:p.?    NM_000138.4 . . .
2   chr15   48741091    FBN1:NM_000138.4:exon46:c.5546-1G>A:p.? NM_000138.4 . . .
3   chr15   48807637    FBN1:NM_000138.4:exon12:c.1415G>A:p.Cys472Tyr   NM_000138.4 . . .
4   chr15   48741091    FBN1:NM_000138.4:exon46:c.5546-1G>A:p.?,FBN1:NM_000138.4:exon46:c.5546-1G>T:p.? NM_000138.4 . . . CS057008 DM
```

Comment: The `awk` works, but how does `$6` get updated? In my actual data there are several fields after `$6`. Thank you :).

Comment: @Chris, could you please add example on what you are mentioning sorry didn't get it.

Comment: I added `C1 in `$7` and `C2` in `$8` of  `file2`. If `$6` was getting updated does that need to be specified in the `print` statement? Otherwise the last field gets updated it looks like? Thank you :).

Comment: @Chris, please check my updated codes and let me know if that helps you?

Comment: the `C1` and `C2` are not always the headers and there are several after those. The code works great as is but updates the last column in `file2`. How can `$6` in `file2` be updated even if that is not the last column? Thank you :).

Comment: my apologies the `C1` and `C2` are in `file1` not `file2`.... I apologize for the typo.  Thank you very much :).

Comment: Why `print $0,"C1" OFS "C2"` instead of `print $0, "C1", "C2"`?

Comment: @Chris, you need `C1` and `C2` in output right? if yes then my previous solutions it self would have worked for you. If you have any queries then please be more clear in your question.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13, `C1` and `C2` are in `file1` making that 8 fields. After running the script `$6` should be  updated. Leaving `$7, and `$8` unchanged. There are several files after in my actual data besides `C1` and `C2.Currently the last field in `file1` is updated, in this example it is `$8`. Thank you :).

Comment: @Chris, please change your expected output in your post and let me know then.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I have updated the output to reflect the change, `file1` has 8 fields in it and after the script runs `$6` is updated while the rest remains unchanged. The files are `tab-delimited` though I think the spacing is off.  Thank you :).

Comment: @Chris, if your files are tab delimited then put `-F"\t"` after `awk` and for taking them output as tab delimited you could either use `OFS="\t"` before input_files names or you could pipe this command to ` | column -t` I believe output is coming correct only, please check once. I have added output and my command in my post too now.